# Two contradicting derivations of the Covariance Matrix for Linear Regression

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, linear

I am looking to compute the variance covariance matrix for the standard linear regression coefficients $\hat{\beta}$ when:
$$Y = X \beta + \epsilon $$
and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. I have derived this in two different ways but I am getting contradicting results and would like help figuring out where my derivation has gone wrong.

Method 1 (The correct method):
$$
\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\beta}|X) &= Var( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y) \\\\
&= Var( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T (X \beta + \epsilon)) \\\\
&= Var( \beta + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T\epsilon)) \\\\
&=  (X^T X)^{-1}Var(\epsilon)) \\\\
&=  (X^T X)^{-1}\sigma^2 \\\\
&\approx (X^T X)^{-1}\hat{\sigma}^2 
\end{align}
$$

Method 2 (The incorrect method):
Here, instead of waiting for the end to replace a random variable with its estimate, we start by replacing $Y = X \beta + \epsilon$ with $Y^* = X \hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon}$. Doing this results in:

$$
\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\beta}|X) &= Var( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y) \\\\
&\approx Var( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y^*) \\\\
&= Var( (X^T X)^{-1} X^T (X \hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= Var(  \hat{\beta} + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= Var(  (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= Var(  (X^T X)^{-1} X^T (X \beta + \epsilon) + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= Var(   \beta + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T  \epsilon) + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= Var(    (X^T X)^{-1} X^T  ( \epsilon) +\hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= (X^T X)^{-1} Var( \epsilon +\hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= (X^T X)^{-1} (Var( \epsilon)  +Var(\hat{\epsilon}) - 2 Cov(\epsilon, \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&= (X^T X)^{-1} (\sigma^2  +Var(\hat{\epsilon}) - 2 Cov(\epsilon, \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
&\approx (X^T X)^{-1} (\hat{\sigma}^2  +Var(\hat{\epsilon}) - 2 Cov(\epsilon, \hat{\epsilon})) \\\\
\end{align}
$$

Which is definitely not equivalent to the first method. Why is this so? Are both cases approximations for the variance covariance matrix, but the former is a better approximation than the latter (which I believe is wider). Is it better practice to only replace a parameter with its approximation rather than replacing a distribution with our best approximation of it? Or is it because $Y^*$ is a different realization than the original Y?

Comment: The reason is that you do too many unnecessary algebraic manipulations and go astray in the middle.  This isn't a stats question: it's an algebra question.

Comment: In particular, compare the RHS of your line 1 and line 5. Also, the variance of different residuals is different and they aren't independent, so $\mathrm{var}[\hat\epsilon]$ can't just be treated as a single number like $\mathrm{var}[\epsilon]$ can.